# E: Malformed line 54 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)

Tags: apt

The command `sudo apt-get update` returns

```
E: Malformed line 54 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
```

as output. Please help me to solve this issue.

Here are lines 53 and 54 in the source list:

```
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/lucid partner
```

Comment: Why did you edit this by hand? Always make sure you have a backup of the file to compare against if you have issues. And please keep in mind that 10.04 is an older unsupported release (desktop, not server).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an unsupported End-of-Life release. 10.04 Desktop edition was marked end-of-life at May 9, 2013 and the partner repository isn't updated anymore for Lucid since then. I do recognize that your question is not strictly about that, though (so I provided an answer).

Comment: I never edited it but thanx for the answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line 54 should be

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
```